# How to make this Regex pattern work for both strings

Tags: python, regex

I have the strings `'amount $165'` and `'amount on 04/20'` (and a few other variations I have no issues with so far). I want to be able to run an expression and return the numerical amount IF available (in the first string it is `165`) and return nothing if it is not available AND make sure not to confuse with a date (second string). If I write the code as following, it returns the `165` but it also returns `04` from the second.

```
 amount_search = re.findall(r'amount.*?(\d+)[^\d?/]?, string)
```

If I write it as following, it includes neither

```
amount_search = re.findall(r'amount.*?(\d+)[^\d?/], string)
```

How to change what I have to return `165` but not `04`?

Comment: What is the *rule* for determining whether a substring contains a "numerical amount"? Presumable a string of one or more digits preceded by `"$"` is an "amount". What about `"$12-22-2019"`? `"30"`? `"$1,200.61"`? `"$1,200.6a"`? `".12"`?`"30 May 2019"`? `".12"`? `"1.2.3"`? `"12."`? `"14 15"`? Be precise!

Answer (score 1):

To capture the whole number in a group, you could match amount followed by matching all chars except digits or newlines if the value can not cross newline boundaries.

Capture the first encountered digits in a group and assert a whitespace boundary at the right.

```
\bamount [^\d\r\n]*(\d+)(?!\S)
```

In parts

- `\bamount`  Match amount followed by a space and preceded with a word boundary
- `[^\d\r\n]*` Match 0 or more times any char except a digit or newlines
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1 or more digits
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary on the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XhHEzp/1)

Answer (score 0):

try this `^amount\W*\$([\d]{1,})$`

the `$` indicate end of line, for what I have tested, use `.*` or `?` also work.
by grouping the digits, you can eliminate the `/` inside the date format.

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from re import sub
your_digit_list = [int(sub(r'[^0-9]', '', s)) for s in str.split() if s.lstrip('$').isdigit()]
```